# Excluding certain elements from Array.prototype.indexOf.call

Tags: javascript, dom

```
var el = clickedElement;
var chl = el.closest('li');
var prt = chl.parentNode;
var idx = Array.prototype.indexOf.call(prt.children, chl);
```

Im using this code to get the index number of clickedElement from the parentNode.. it works most of time.. i want to be able to filter out some elements from the index number

For example..

```
li.zero
li.first
h2
li.second
```

If I try this code to get li.second element as index 2 it gives me index '3' because of that h3 tag inbetween..
How can i exclude certain elements from counting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the [`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method.

It might look something like this:

```js
var idx = Array.prototype.indexOf.call(
  Array.from(prt.children)
    .filter(domNode => domNode.tagName.toLowerCase() === "li"), 
  chl
);
```

Now you will only check the index for list item elements.

Comment: great! THank you!